# how to stop css/jquery rotation

Tags: jquery, css

I have a function that makes a gear rotate on the page after an element is clicked, i found the code online and edited a little bit to make it compatible with what i need, however i cannot figure out how to make it run on a timer (maybe 2 seconds?). can anyone give me a hand?

```
$(".go1").click(function() {
    var $spin = $(".gear1"), degree = 0, timer;
    rotate();
    function rotate() {

        $spin.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        $spin.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
    timer = 2000,setTimeout(function() {
            ++degree; rotate();
        },50);

    }


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y2tjX/

this is how it looks, the jsfiddle isnt working though (maybe i didnt put enough of the code) but in the whole of the actual file, the gear spins as desired when go1 is clicked but doesnt stop spinning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forked from roXon: http://jsfiddle.net/HWfMt/

The key is to stop the recursive setTimeout() calls after 2 seconds, each time you click.

```
var degree = 0;
var timer=30;
var $spin = $(".gear1");
var to;

$(".go1").click(function() {
    rotate();
     setTimeout(function(){
     clearTimeout(to);
 },2000);

});

function rotate() {
    degree++;
    $spin.css({ 'WebkitTransform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
    $spin.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
    to = setTimeout(function() {
        rotate();
    }, timer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read up on javascript timers: 
http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

You can then use the setInterval method to do something like this:

```
var degree = 0;
$(".go1").click(function() { setInterval("rotate()", 2000); });

function rotate( )
{
    var $spin = $(".gear1"), degree = 0, timer;
    $spin.css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
    $spin.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});
    degree = degree + 1;
}
```

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted it to just spin every 2 seconds regardless of a click action. Please see the updated solution.

Comment: I changed var degree = 0. If you can provide me with a jsfiddle, I'll make it spin! lol

Comment: ill make a working jsfiddle once i get home from work, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
var degree=0;
var timer=2000;

$(".go1").click(function() {
    rotate();
});

function rotate() {
    var $spin = $(".gear1");
    time=0;
    while(time<timer) {
        $spin.css({ 'WebkitTransform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'});  
        $spin.css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'}); 
        ++time;   
        ++degree;
    });
}
```

Comment: this works kinda off opposite of what i need haha, this caused a delay between clicking the element and the rotation, im trying to make the rotation start right away but stop after 2 seconds. thansk for the help!

Comment: Give the edited version above a try. It should work a little better.

Comment: this actually did the same thing as before but it was a lot more choppy :/

Comment: Ha! OK. Good luck, it should be getting closer.

Comment: OK give that one a try. Changed up the logic a bit.

Comment: this didnt spin at all, the code i gave works pretty much how i want it to except it doesnt stop spinning

Comment: One more try for me and I am out. That one should spin but it might go 1000 miles an hour.